# I'd like notification to have a different background color when it isn't directed at me

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications, user-experience, follow-posts

As most of you know, there is a rather [new feature released that allows users to follow chosen posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network):

> After you have followed a post, you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question), comments, edits, and notices.

I'd like to be able to differentiate between when I receive a notification from a followed post, and when I receive a notification that was directed at me.

**Currently, whenever users receive a notification, there will a number surrounded by red on the notifications box.**

[image]

**I'd like it to instead, for example, be surrounded by blue when I receive a notification that *wasn't directed at me.***

[image]

[image: Inbox item for a comment from followed question. The comment does not @ mention the OP.]

**For when there are both kinds of notifications:**

[image: The background for the notification number is red on the left half and blue on the right.]

That way, while I'm working on some code that requires a lot of concentration, when I receive a blue notification, I won't have to worry about neglecting an important notification.

*(Also, at times, I'd be excited to receive a notification, but get slightly disappointed to find that it wasn't directed at me.)*

Comment: You don't get notifications for bookmarks. Maybe you could just bookmark something if you don't want notifications for it?

Comment: @BSMP Why would I follow a post if I don't want notifications?

Comment: I thought this question was about not wanting notifications that aren't about you?

Comment: @BSMP No, it's to the have the advantage of knowing how to react when I receive the two kinds of notifications. Like I *know* I followed a post that wasn't too important, and don't want to get interrupted by clicking on the notifications box and reading the first line when I'm concentrating on something else.

Comment: The diamond that notifies moderators there's a new meta post or a new moderator message lights up with a different color when there's something else the team wants to draw attention to. And that's very helpful. I don't see why the same thing can't happen for user notifications as well. I agree it can be disappointing to click on the new notification icon only to find out it's an automated message about an election you couldn't care less about...

Comment: All notifications in the inbox are directed at you. If they weren't, they shouldn't show up in the inbox.

Comment: @CodyGray https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa6sp.png

Comment: @CodyGray this is only your opinion. To me for example, there _is_ a difference. Although my priorities are opposite to those of the OP (I value followed / election notifications over those from @-comments) I would also benefit from being able to visually distinguish these

Comment: If you don't want to get notifications, then don't follow the question. I hate notifications, so I don't follow posts. Since you opted in to following them, they are, by definition, also directed at you.

Comment: @CodyGray You don't seem to understand. I replied that in the above comments.

Comment: ^^^ you _really_ don't understand @CodyGray - these are notifications from followed questions that I _want_ to get and I have explicitly chosen to get. This is opposite to notifications from @-comments where I have zero power to decide whether I want them or not, system will deliver these to me no matter what. If you weren't so focused on something else (possibly on attempt to justify downvote) you could be able to discover this difference yourself. It is not complicated

Comment: I think this would be just as useful as thanks reaction.

Comment: @oguzismail But there are no downsides to this feature; the thanks feature did have downsides.

Comment: There is though, it'd be very distracting.

Comment: Upvoted only because of how colorful it is.

Comment: What about color blind people?

Comment: @AndrewMyers Well, if it were red and green, there could be a problem, but red and blue will differentiate more.

Answer (score 7):

This is a clever idea in my opinion, and would add context to the notification alerts. I don't currently utilize the "follow" feature for posts, but if I ever do, I would appreciate knowing at a glance if I received:

- A response to *me*, (e.g. @TylerH), or an action on one of my posts like accepting, up/down voting, closing, etc.,

versus:

- A 'following' notification, or someone commenting @someone-else under one of my posts instead (e.g. something I can probably ignore).

Orthogonally, I think it might be better to have this for Meta vs Main rather than direct vs indirect activity.